# CiviReport 'insufficient permission' error running financial report after update to 4.7.29

Tags: civireport, 4.7, permissions, roles

Only since upgrading CiviCRM to 4.7.29 from 4.7.11 (on Drupal), one of my users with 'editor' role is unable to run a financial report. The error she sees is:

```
"API permission check failed for FinancialAccount/get call; 
insufficient permission: require administer CiviCRM"
```

I can't believe she should need full admin rights just to run this report. On 4.7.11 it wasn't necessary.

Is there a recommended way to investigate the error and see whether assigning a lesser permission to the 'editor' role would restore normal service? The upgrade process warned of a new permission 'manage tags' but nothing to do with Financial Accounts or CiviContribute.

Comment: Same here on a CiviCRM 5.3.1. Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been reported at [Bookkeeping Transactions Report insufficient permissions](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/551) and from CiviCRM 5.9 will be fixed. [Here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/commit/458b173b3dcdefdb379df6abc0bc2da413fc51b0) the affected code.